# Just installed Ubuntu, how do I install Internet drivers?

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, internet

as of right now I have no way of connecting to the wireless networks in my fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04. My wireless adapter is a TP-Link Archer T4u ac1200. I have another computer that I will be able to install drivers from over USB, but I'm not sure how. I have absolutely no internet at all and also, I can't install drivers in additional software either. I'm pretty sure Ethernet will work but I am unable to move my PC downstairs near my modem. How can I make it so that I can connect to wifi?

**Edit**

The output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087: 8088 Intel Corp
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux foundation 2.0 Root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 device 006: ID 04b4:1007 Cypress Semiconductor Corp
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bc2:ab10 Seagate RSS LLC
Bus 001 device 003: ID 1b1c:1b12 Corsair
Bus 001 device 007: ID 0d8c:016c C-Media electronics, INC
Bus 001 device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I obviously see my M65 RGB (Corsair) and my external HDD (Seagate RSS LLC) but I'm not too sure about my keyboard, which is an AZIO MGK1-RGB.

Comment: what is the output of 'lspci | grep -i network'?

Comment: When I enter that command in terminal I don't get any output at all.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lsusb`. You may omit all listings that are not the wireless device if you wish.

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: Was the Archer USB wireless plugged in at the time? I don't see it.

Comment: Yes it was. It was working perfectly on Windows before.

Comment: Please remove the Archer USB wireless. Open a terminal and do: `tail -f /var/log/syslog` Insert the USB wireless and tell us what messages appear in the terminal. Any identifying data will be most helpful. Get out of 'tail' with Ctrl+c. Here is an example from my machine: "New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271" The vendor and product identification are crucial.

Comment: I get the error "no such file or directory"

Comment: Please check your command again. Every successful installation of Ubuntu has a file `/var/log/syslog` Make sure you didn't type: `var/log/syslog` or even: `/var/logsyslog`.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake in mistyping, I got idVendor=2357 and idProduct=0101

Answer (score 0):

One of the packages you need, *dkms*, is on the install DVD or USB; insert it and drill down to pool > main > d > dkms and drag dkms to you desktop. Then install:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
```

Now download this package on some other computer and transfer it by USB or similar to your desktop: https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/archive/master.zip Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, back to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dkms add ./rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
sudo dkms install -m 8812au -v 1.0
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

NOTE: This depends on the presence of *build-essential* and *linux-headers-generic*. Please check:

```
sudo dpkg -s build-essential
sudo dpkg -s linux-headers-generic
```

If either is not installed, I will edit my answer to propose a further solution.

Comment: I don't have a DVD drive, I got rid of it because it made the front panel of my case look ugly. I don't have a way to use the driver install DVD. Or do you mean the USB I used to install Ubuntu? That won't work either, it won't allow me to access those files.

Comment: Yes, the Ubuntu install USB. Why are you unable to access those files? Are you running Ubuntu from the USB or is this a full installation?